# Static function definition that resembles a pointer to member function

Tags: c++

I'm looking into the LLVM source code and I never encountered the following syntax:

```
class BasicBlock {
 public:
  typedef iplist<Instruction> InstListType;
 private:
  InstListType InstList;

  static iplist<Instruction> BasicBlock::*getSublistAccess(Instruction*) {
    return &BasicBlock::InstList;
  }
}
```

what does the above define? At first it seemed a normal static function but I don't understand the `BasicBlock::*` part. Seems like a static function which returns a member function pointer and that directly executes that member function's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of static member function `getSublistAccess` is

```
iplist<Instruction> BasicBlock::*
```

that is, a pointer to a non-static data member of class `BasicBlock`, where the data type is `iplist<Instruction>`.

What `getSublistAccess` actually returns is `&BasicBlock::InstList`, that is exactly a non-static data member of class `BasicBlock`, where the data type is `InstListType`. i.e., `iplist<Instruction>`.

Comment: Thanks, the `Instruction*` parameter is not used, right?

Comment: No, it's not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is a function pointer.
You can read **[this article](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi)** for detail.

Comment: `getSublistAccess` is not a function pointer. Try out the code I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **iavr** for the answer. I'm awarding the answer to him but I'd like to add some details here which will hopefully help someone reading this post.

What I asked and as iavr explained to me, might be understood with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct customType {
    int b;
    };
struct Instruction {};

class BasicBlock {
public:

 BasicBlock(int a) { InstList.b = a; }
 customType InstList;

  static customType BasicBlock::*getSublistAccess(Instruction*) {
    return &BasicBlock::InstList;
  }
};

int main() {

    BasicBlock bb(90);

    Instruction justForSignature;
    // Get a pointer to a member of type customType through the static function
    customType BasicBlock::* ptrToMember = BasicBlock::getSublistAccess(&justForSignature);

    cout << (bb.*ptrToMember).b; // Parenthesis are necessary, '.' has higher precedence on *
    // Output: 90

    return 0;
}
```

Try it out: http://ideone.com/hYgfh8

Comment: By the way, to get a pointer to function, one would need extra parentheses: `iplist<Instruction> (BasicBlock::*getSublistAccess)(Instruction*)`.